# What does this C snippet do

Tags: c

I've tried to figure it out with comments but not sure if my intuition is right.

```
char *foo(char *s, int n)
{
    char s2[10];     /* Create a empty string of size 10 */
    char *c;          /* Declare a pointer to a char */
    strcpy(s2, s);  /* Copy s into s2 */
    c = s2;         /* Set c equal to the beginning of s2 */
    while(*c++);    /* Move c to the end of  s2 */
    *c = (n > 1) ? 's' : 0; /* If argument is greater than 1 change last char to a s, otherwise 0 */
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: This is mostly correct, but the `*c =..` is not about the last character, but about the null-terminator.

Comment: Looks like it's intended to pluralize a word, given the number, but it's very broken.

Comment: It yields undefined behaviour, that's what it does. `s2` is a local variable in `foo`, you cannot return it, because `s2` is only valid until `foo` returns. Also this code does not take into account the size of `s2`, if the source string is longer than 9 characters, then you have a buffer overflow which yield undefined behaviour.

Comment: This looks like one of those, *"Tell me everything that's wrong with this code"* interview questions.

Comment: @machine_1 I think the OP is the author of the comments. Not sure why it is downvoted so heavily though...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, you're right.. but the the way he wrote didn't directly suggest that.

Comment: @machine_1 Please read the question, it states I wrote the comments but am unsure about my reasoning.

Comment: @user3386109  Agree about a likely interview question.  At least 6 issues.

Answer (score 7):

The intention of the code is **to dumbly pluralise** (append an `'s'`) a word informed in argument `s` by considering the number informed in argument `n`. In other words (if the code was correct), if `n > 1`, then it appends an `s` to the end of the string.

However, the presented code will not work because of many errors:

1. It assumes the string informed in `s` won't be longer than 8 characters (8 + 's' + '\0'), otherwise the function may crash the process or cause other undesired effects - You should use safer functions to perform string copying;
2. The loop used to move the pointer to the end of the string, increments the pointer until it's too late. It stops after the `\0` (nul terminator), because the post-increment operator (++) is always executed, despite the result of the condition. It should be `while (*c) c++;`;
3. It returns an invalid pointer to a local variable `s2`, which may cause multiple problems in the program, including a crash - You should dynamically allocate memory for the result, or pass a pointer as argument, indicating where the string will be stored, and how many bytes it can take;
4. It doesn't terminate the *new string* properly - there's no guarantee the string will contain another '\0' after the appended `'s'`.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet that you provide is a very bad coding example. It has a lot of issues:

- The object `s2` is declared as a local array with a limited size of 10, and it is passed as an argument to `strcpy()` without any bounds checking, which opens the door for possible overflow.
- If the value of the parameter `n` is greater than 1, then the terminating character of the string is replaced by `'s'`, which could cause undefined behavior if used incorrectly, such as being passed to a function like `printf()`.
- It returns the address of a local variable, which if de-referenced will yeild undefined behavior.

Comment: Detail about "if de-referenced will yeild undefined behavior":  Passing the return pointer back itself is UB - even if the calling code does not use it.

Comment: @chux Are you sure? Can you quote anything from the standard?

Comment: With `char *a; a  = foo(..); bar(*a);`  we agree `*a` is UB.  100% that the assignment `a = foo()` is also UB (assignment of invalid value).  What remains: is `foo(..);` by itself UB.  That I am 90% confident it is UB.  Would make a good question if  not all ready a dupe.  IAC, certain we agree code should not return `s2`.

Comment: @chux I am almost(99.99%) certain it is not UB.

Comment: @chux Why `a = foo()` is UB?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is the same as `a = (char*) (867-5309);`  An assignment to a pointer (`a`), is valid only if the value given is a valid pointer for the type or a _null pointer_.  Scratch this sample - let me try agian.

Comment: @chux Hm. I can't find it in the standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is similar to `void *a = malloc(42); free(a); printf("%p", a);` - and given our comments, may deserve a SO question.  Have not yet found a dupe or C spec either.

Comment: @chux Good luck with that, but if you got downvoted heavily, it's not our fault :-)

Comment: @chux Found it: *The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.* - [Here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16). Yet I don't think `int x; x;` is UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So _assigning_ an _indeterminate_ pointer like `a = indeterminate;` could assign a trap-value.  "A trap representation is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type
(6.2.6.1)." may apply as well as "Note that fetching a trap
representation might perform a trap but is not required".  A such a [can of worms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/can_of_worms).

Comment: @chux OK, so in my example `x` could be a trap representation. And `x;` is actually fetching it. Uh-oh...

Comment: @chux I can't find any dupe. Do you still think it is worth posting a question regarding this issue?

Comment: @machine_1 Unless a dupe is found, I think it is worth posting.  Yet posting such is _work_ to well cite specs and prior posts for such a probing issue.  Have at it if you like. maybe I will in the next months otherwise.